# MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() gives wrong date in certain time zones?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

The timestamps `1382836533` and `1382832933` correspond to the same wall clock time `2013-10-27 02:15:33` in `cet` timezone (because of daylight savings time).

Therefore the conversion with `FROM_UNIXTIME` is lossy.

```
mysql> set time_zone = 'CET';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533));
+-------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533)) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                1382832933 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a field of type `timestamp` in my database. If I want to update it, with my time zone settings, I end up writing the wrong value to the database:

```
mysql> update test set begins_at = from_unixtime(1382836533);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select unix_timestamp(begins_at) from test;
+---------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(begins_at) |
+---------------------------+
|                1382832933 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The problem does not occur when I manually set the connection time zone to `UTC.

It *does* occur when I manually set the connection time zone to `CET`.

But it does *not* occur when I do nothing. Which is strange because the server *and* client have both `CET` as their default time zone.

So the question is: Why does the problem not occur when I don't manually set the timezone? And what precise combinations of server and connection time zones produce this problems and which do not?

The log below reflects the behaviour.

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show variables like '%zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | CET    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533));
+-------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533)) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                1382836533 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select from_unixtime(1382836533);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1382836533) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-10-27 02:15:33       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select from_unixtime(1382832933);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1382832933) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-10-27 02:15:33       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set time_zone = 'CET';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533));
+-------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(1382836533)) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                1382832933 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select from_unixtime(1382832933);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1382832933) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-10-27 02:15:33       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select from_unixtime(1382836533);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1382836533) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-10-27 02:15:33       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I just realised that the problem seems to only appear with specific timestamps? 1382836533 is such a time stamp, but another works just fine. WTF!

Comment: Please `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Comment: [Essentially a cross-post from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41667609/1695906).

Comment: I had the problems in a PHP script and could not figure it out, thats why i was on stack overflow. I first thought it was a PHP or PDO issue. Then I realised it was a pure DB issue .

Comment: I suggest you flag your SO question for migration here (then we can merge them). No need for 2 questions.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ done